# Scrollbars not appearing in popup window

Tags: javascript, web-applications, popup

I am trying to bring up a popup on click of a link . When the data overflows , the scrollbars are not appearing in the popup. Below is the code written to bring up the popup.

```
 function accessPrevilagesPopup(role){
        var url="initAccessPrevilagesAction.action?role="+role;
        window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, status=no,width=700, height=350,top=250,left=250");   
    }
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you show the markup and CSS of the popup window?

Comment: It is a big file . Can you say which part of css you are suspecting ?

Comment: It might be that there is an `overflow: hidden` somewhere.

Comment: just a quick suggestion, add scrollbars=yes to the 3-rd param of window.open and check if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function accessPrevilagesPopup(role){
        var url="initAccessPrevilagesAction.action?role="+role;
        window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, status=no,width=700, height=350,top=250,left=250,scrollbars=1");   
    }
```